# "Undefined property" error when using CodeIgniter db and active record

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to insert demo records from some simple form using active records and codeigniter

```
function create_httpPost()
{
   $data = array(
      'title' => $this->input->post('title'),
      'content' => $this->input->post('content')
   );

   $this->newsModel->createData($data); //error occures here
   $this->index();//aka redirectToAction
}
```

but after posting form I'm getting following error

> **Message: Undefined property: News::$newsModel
>
> Filename: controllers/news.php Line Number: 29**

Inside model I have this method

```
function createData($data)
    {
        $this->db->insert('News', $data);
        return;
    }
```

what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Did you load the model?

Comment: @yes autoload inside autoload.php

Answer (score 2):

According to the CodeIgniter documentation, model class names must begin by an upper case letter with the rest of the name being lower case.

See:  http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/models.html

In the section titled **Anatomy of a Model:**

> Class names must have the first letter capitalized with the rest of the name lowercase...
>   The file name will be a lower case version of your class name.

In your case, `newsModel` violates the rule, and the CodeIgniter name parser is probably not finding the class (or the relevant .php file), which is why it thinks `newsModel` is a property (that does not exist).

Comment: Correct, the filename of the model should be `news_model.php` and the class name should be `News_model`. This will allow the autoloader to load the model and provide you access to it through `$this->news_model`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function create_httpPost()
{
   $this->load->model('newsModel'); // you need to load model

   $this->newsModel->createData(array(
      'title'   => $this->input->post('title', TRUE),
      'content' => $this->input->post('content', TRUE)
   ));

   $this->index();
}
```

Comment: According to the OP, autoload is loading the model.

Answer (score -1):

This is very comman problem with CI2.

this function must be inside one of ur models right ?

if so, please note that `u can't reference model from inside other model` ! for some reason. u need to let controller handle that

Comment: You can access other models from within a model. If it is not autoloaded however, you would need to load it.